# php logic arrays and old vs new variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, logic

This is my issue, it feels simple but I'm missing something.

I have an array (row in a mysql table):

```
id 125
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3000.000

id 122
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3000.000

id 125
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 3000.000

id 122
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3000.000
```

I need to total `array[0]` per unique id:

```
id[122] = 4;
id[125] = 7;
```

So far i have :

```
while($get_movementsr=mysql_fetch_array($get_movements)){

    $qty = $get_movementsr['qty'];
    $newid = $get_movementsr['id'];

//here i want to load an array
//if the next id in the loop is the same i want it to add else if its not the same
//a new array id musty be created and total, basically check for new variable vs old //variable - im a noob sorry guys 

 $total[$newid] += $qty;

    $old = $newid;
}
```

Comment: why not use MySQL SUM() function??

Comment: You have described an array structure with the arrays indexed by integer, and then shown code with the arrays indexed by name.  Which is it?  Double check that you've got what you think you have by var dumping $get_movementsr inside your loop.

Comment: I could use a new mysql query to do what i need done but i thought id try grab the totals using an array - just me learning arrays -

Comment: This is my main array im trying to get the productsid and quantity into separate arr then total Array
(
    [0] => 1010
    [batchnumber] => 1010
    [1] => Lid /9 White 3000 MD
    [Product] => Lid /9 White 3000 MD
    [2] => Lid
    [Type] => Lid
    [3] => White
    [color] => White
    [4] => 
    [Machine] => 
    [5] => 2013-11-20 13:01:12
    [datetimeval] => 2013-11-20 13:01:12
    [6] => 8.00000
    [weight] => 8.00000
    [7] => 3000.000
    [quantity] => 3000.000
    [8] => buy-outs
    [page_name] => buy-outs
    [9] => 2
    [typeid] => 2
    [10] => 125
    [productsid] => 125
)

Answer (score 0):

If you define  `$total` outside the loop, you get what you want...

```
$total = array();

while($get_movementsr=mysql_fetch_array($get_movements)){
    $qty = $get_movementsr['qty'];
    $newid = $get_movementsr['id'];

    $total[$newid] += $qty;
}
```

Comment: This partially gets me to where i want to be but i think the array structure is wrong and it is not calculating the values correctlyall row qty's for array[125] have a value off 3000 there are 3 rows so its total should be 9000 instead it is 18000 this is a dump of the $total array using print_r.Array
(
    [125] => 3000
)
Array
(
    [125] => 9000
)
Array
(
    [125] => 18000
)
Array
(
    [125] => 18000
    [124] => 14500
)

Comment: Found the problem $qty = $get_movementsr['qty']; i had made it a += not just an = however this does not fully solve my problem each loop it makes it creates a new index is it not possible to just add to the array value each time instead of creating an index Array
(
    [125] => Array
        (
            [client] => Lid /9 White 3000 MD
            [qty] => 3000
            [weight] => 8
        )

)
Array
(
    [125] => Array
        (
            [client] => Lid /9 White 3000 MD
            [qty] => 6000
            [weight] => 16
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

```
//(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)
function total($result, $field)
{
    return count(array_column($result, $field));
}
```